# Spring Data JPA Custom Methods & Component Injection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dependency-injection

I configured a Spring Data JPA Custom Method extending my app repository functionalities. I referenced this tutorial [link](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-into-all-repositories/) and It works properly. I implemented the custom method because I have to set the user in all the JPA Entities before persisting.

This is the BaseRepository interface.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends AuditableBean, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S save(S bean);

}
```

This is the BaseRepository Implementation

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl <T extends AuditableBean, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

    @Inject private CloudContextProvider cloudContextProvider; // <-- I inject this component here but it is null.

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public T populateUser(T t) {
        t.setUpdaterUser(cloudContextProvider.getUserId());// <-- Here throws a NPE
        return t;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S bean) {
        this.auditUser(bean);// <-- This is the custom method.
        return super.save(bean);
    }

    public T auditUser(T t) {
        t = populateUser(t);
        return t;
    }
}
```

So the question is, ¿How can I inject the cloudContextProvider component in the BaseRepositoryImpl?.

Is that possible?

Maybe with constructor injection?